# Failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "/init": permission denied: unknow

Tags: docker, dockerfile, home-assistant

I am using the open source code of home assistant.
The command which I used for the build is:-

```
docker build --build-arg BUILD_FROM=homeassistant/amd64-homeassistant-base:latest . -t homeassistant:local
```

After tagging and pushing it on dockerhub, I am using the following command to run the image:-

```
sudo docker run -d --name homeassistant --privileged --restart=unless-stopped -v /home/smhmlab/Dashboard/HomeAssistant:/config --network=host keshavr/ha-repo:custom-0.31.88
```

After while running this command, I am getting the error as:-

```
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "/init": permission denied: unknown.
```

The content of the **Dockerfile** is as follows:-

```
ARG BUILD_FROM
FROM ${BUILD_FROM}

# Synchronize with homeassistant/core.py:async_stop
ENV \
S6_SERVICES_GRACETIME=220000

ARG QEMU_CPU

WORKDIR /usr/src

## Setup Home Assistant Core dependencies
COPY requirements.txt homeassistant/
COPY homeassistant/package_constraints.txt homeassistant/homeassistant/
RUN \
pip3 install \
    --no-cache-dir \
    --no-index \
    --only-binary=:all: \
    --find-links "${WHEELS_LINKS}" \
    -r homeassistant/requirements.txt

COPY requirements_all.txt home_assistant_frontend-* home_assistant_intents-* 
homeassistant/
RUN \
if ls homeassistant/home_assistant_frontend*.whl 1> /dev/null 2>&1; then \
    pip3 install \
        --no-cache-dir \
        --no-index \
        homeassistant/home_assistant_frontend-*.whl; \
fi \
&& if ls homeassistant/home_assistant_intents*.whl 1> /dev/null 2>&1; then \
    pip3 install \
        --no-cache-dir \
        --no-index \
        homeassistant/home_assistant_intents-*.whl; \
fi \
&& \
    LD_PRELOAD="/usr/local/lib/libjemalloc.so.2" \
    MALLOC_CONF="background_thread:true,metadata_thp:auto,dirty_decay_ms:20000,muzzy_decay_ms:20000" \
    pip3 install \
        --no-cache-dir \
        --no-index \
        --only-binary=:all: \
        --find-links "${WHEELS_LINKS}" \
        -r homeassistant/requirements_all.txt

## Setup Home Assistant Core
COPY . homeassistant/
RUN \
pip3 install \
    --no-cache-dir \
    --no-index \
    --only-binary=:all: \
    --find-links "${WHEELS_LINKS}" \
    -e ./homeassistant \
&& python3 -m compileall \
    homeassistant/homeassistant

# Home Assistant S6-Overlay
COPY rootfs /

WORKDIR /config
```

Is there any solution to resolve this error?
Please let me know in case any other information is needed to resolve this issue.